# Swift - How to animate Images?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to animate images in particular time- duration. It is working fine in Objective C. However, it is not working for Swift, where is my mistake?

**The code for Objective-C is -**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSMutableArray *imgListArray=[NSMutableArray array];
   for (int i=0; i<=11; i++)

   {
       NSString *strImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d.png", i];
       NSLog(@"%@",strImageName);
       UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:strImageName];
       [imgListArray addObject:image];
   }

   self.imgView.animationImages = imgListArray;
   self.imgView.animationDuration =1.0f;    
   [self.imgView startAnimating];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
}
```

**The Code for swift is-**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var imgListArray :NSMutableArray = []
   for countValue in 1...11
   {
      var strImageName : String = "c\(countValue).png"
      var image = UIImage(named:strImageName) // suggested by Anil
      imgListArray.addObject(image)
   }

   // Swift code HERE for Objective c
}
```

Comment: what is that line, `var image  = [UIImage imageNamed (strImageName)]`? what is that syntax? an array? or a mixture of ObjC and _Swift_?

Comment: @holex in objective c , it is working fine but  i m not getting idea about swift conversion.

Comment: you may look for this: `var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: strImageName)`

Comment: @holex y a i got ur point and modified it in my question now i want to animate it...

Comment: you have to finish converting the ObjC code to _Swift_...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
[UIImage imageNamed (strImageName)]
```

This not swift code. In swift it would be

```
UIImage(named:strImageName)
```

Modified code:

```
var imgListArray :NSMutableArray = []
for countValue in 1...11
    {

        var strImageName : String = "c\(countValue).png"
        var image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
        imgListArray .addObject(image)
    }

    self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: thanks.... and i m not able to do animation.  in objective c , i have used the above code, in swift, i m not getting any idea..

Comment: There might be cases where `NSMutableArray` doesn't work. If you start getting weird errors regarding the mutable array try using generics. `var imageList Array<AnyObject> = []`

Comment: How does the code change if I'm using a packed image file? Meaning all the animations are in one file!?

Comment: @Anil Varghese. I am getting url list of images then how to handle it here

Answer (score 24):

for Swift 2, use `[UIImage]` instead.

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
for i in 1...2 {
    images.append(UIImage(named: "c\(i)")!)
}
myImageView.animationImages = images
myImageView.animationDuration = 1.0
myImageView.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 19):

In swift you can go one step further and have a simple line to do this:

```
let loadingImages = (1...11).map { UIImage(named: "c\($0)")! }
```

Then you can do the rest and inject this into an imageView

```
self.imageView.animationImages = loadingImages
self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: thank you for this functional approach! one comment: it will more safe to use flatMap instead map and explicitly unwrapping

Comment: It depends on the scenario and what you prefer. In local images, I prefer to crash (so I know some frame is missing, for instance). If you download them from elsewhere you could avoid explicit unwrapping.

Answer (score 14):

In swift 3 - Create Array of images and just animate that.

```
func animate_images()
{
    let myimgArr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]
    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in 0..<myimgArr.count
    {
        images.append(UIImage(named: myimgArr[i])!)
    }

    imgView_ref.animationImages = images
    imgView_ref.animationDuration = 0.04
    imgView_ref.animationRepeatCount = 2
    imgView_ref.startAnimating()
}
```

And for stop animation just write

```
 imgView_ref.stopAnimating()
```

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 3+

`UIImageViews` can animate images in two different ways (the other answers already cover the first way in deep):

1. - Create an `[UIImage]` array with the images to animate
   - Set the `animationImages` property of the view with this array
   - Set the `animationDuration` property
   - Start the animation
2. - Encapsulate the animation in an `UIImage` using [`animatedImage(with:duration:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624149-animatedimage)
   - Set the normal `image` property of the view

The following code uses [#imageLiterals](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0039-playgroundliterals.md):

```
let images = [img1, img2, img3] // use of #imageLiterals here
let animation = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1)
self.myImageView.image = animation
```

**Pro:**

If you have to change the image of an UIImageView a lot and maybe one of those images should be animated, then you don't have to start/stop the animation every time anymore neither you need to set the animatedImages property back to `nil` to display the image stored in the image property of the image view.

**Con:**

You can't start/stop the animation, if it's encapsulated in a single `UIImage` instead of an array.

---

**More on `#imageLiterals`:**

If you want to use an image literal, either type `imageLiteral` or just type the name of an image from your assets folder and Xcode's code completion will suggest it.

**Further reading:**

- Another good [blog post](https://medium.com/@gurdeep060289/color-image-new-literals-in-the-cocoa-town-7ef4f2710194) about using `#imageLiterals` and `#colorLiterals` with animations to follow.

Answer (score 2):

another approach if you want to animate an array of images:

```
var counter = 1
var timer = NSTimer()
@IBOutlet weak var someImg: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("doSomeAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func doSomeAnimation() {
    //I have four pngs in my project, which are named frame1.png ... and so on


       if counter == 4 {

        counter = 1

        }else {

        counter++
    }

    someImg.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).png")
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running multiple animations, depending on a variable, try the below.

For example, you could run an animation sending 0 or 1 (maybe based on if your app knows its daytime or nighttime):

```
func runAnimation (imgView: UIImageView, arrayPos: Int) {
    let timingArray = [7.0,10.0] //Durations of each
    let frameArray = [43,45]  //Frames for each
    var imgArray: Array<UIImage> = [] //Setup empty array 

    for i in 1 ... frameArray[arrayPos] {
        //Fill empty array with images!!
        let imageToAdd = UIImage(named: "animationNum_\(arrayPos)-frameNum_\(i)")
        imgArray.append(imageToAdd!)
    }
    imgView.animationImages = imgArray
    imgView.animationDuration = timingArray[arrayPos]
    imgView.animationRepeatCount = 2
    imgView.startAnimating()
}
```