# for loop animation not working correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have copied 5 image files into my project, have cast them to the `UIImage` class from strings (not included below), created an `array` for them, and tried to loop through that `array` when I click the `updateIMAGE` button, to essentially create a little animation. The file in the `UIImageView` is `frame1`, but when I try press the button in the simulator it loops straight to the `frame5`.

```
var imageArray: [UIImage] = [frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, frame5]

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func updateIMAGE(sender: AnyObject) {
    for image in 0..<imageArray.count {
        var im = imageArray[image]
        imageView.image = im
        println(im)
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it loops straight to frame5"? Does it not print the other images / strings? Of course only the fifth image will be set!

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You should not expect the UI to be updated in every iteration of the loop. The UI is only updated after all of your code has been run and control is passed back to the system.

Comment: so for-loops are inappropriate in this instance? Is there not a way of breaking it up so that it sets after each iteration?

Comment: Check the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364504/swift-how-to-animate-images

Comment: where is the animation here? you just fast iterate through the images which makes no sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through an array and add an UIImage to array and outside the loop assign that array to the animationImages property of UIImageView, set up duration and run animation:

```
var array: NSMutableArray = []()
for image in 0..<imageArray.count {
    {
        array.addObject(imageArray[image])
    }

    imageView.animationImages = array;
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.5
    imageView.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 1):

To be much more efficient, iOS will combine multiple drawing operations into a single operation, which is 99.99% of the time what developers and their customers want. If you want an animation, you will have to write some code that does animations.

PS. You can iterate directly through an array, you don't need an index variable.