# Repeat a function in set time Intervals

Tags: ios, swift

I'v been using Xcode/Swift for a couple weeks now and I'm currently working on my first little iOS game. Nothing to tricky just trying to learn the program and having some fun. Which leads me to my problem...

...I essentially want the background image I have in my app to change randomly (from a set of values in an array) but timed. So for example "every 2 seconds the background image changes."

This is what I have so far, I've seen some stuff about NSTimer but I'm not too sure how to implement it with what I already have.

```
@IBOutlet weak var backview: UIImageView!

let BackNames = ["Back 1", "Back 2", "Back 3", "Back 4", "Back 5", "Back 6", "Back 7"]

let BackValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))

backview.image = UIImage (named: BackNames [BackValue])
```

So yeah like I said, I know how to make it select a random value for the background, but it only happens when I tap my button. wondering how to incorporate the time feature with my arc4random.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this for animation of image :

```
var imgListArray :NSMutableArray = ["Back 1", "Back 2", "Back 3", "Back 4", "Back 5", "Back 6", "Back 7"]
for countValue in 1...7
    {

        var strImageName : String = "Back \(countValue).png"
        var image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
        imgListArray .addObject(image)
    }

    self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0 // change as per your requirement
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364736/3901620

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!
I've given it a go, but I keep getting the error (with respect to the last three lines) 
"Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'imageView'"

Comment: this is a your backview object of Imageview but i have forgot to change name of this . it is not member of UIviewcontroller but you need define.

Comment: wow quick reply!

I changed the "imageView" in the last three lines to backview and that seems to fix that problem however a new issue has come up w.r.t. ;

self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray;

the error says "cannot assign value type NSMutableArray to type UIImage"

Comment: Hey, just checked the reference you had posted. changing the array helped, however, it cycles through the background images in order, so I'm going to try to figure out how to randomize that as well

Answer (score 1):

Write a Change Color functions and use the function perform selector after delay.

```
func ChangeColor() {
    BackValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(7))

    backview.image = UIImage (named: BackNames [BackValue])

    self.perform(#selector(ChangeColor), with: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
}
```

To cancel selector use

```
self.classForCoder.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was hoping this would work as just by reading it I understood what each line was saying, however...

I keep getting the error message "#selector cannot refer to local function 'Change Color'"

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c;

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(timerCalled:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];

-(void)timerCalled
{
     [UIView transitionWithView:textFieldimageView
                  duration:0.2f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    imageView.image = newImage;
                } completion:nil];
}
```