# Why can not show indicator in Webview on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, viewpagerindicator

I am a beginner in `iOS` development. Now I'm on a page that shows a `webView` when I press a button. I'm marking the `indicator` when I'm loading it. I can't see it. I marked it to be visible when **loading**, but what's the problem?

**storyboard**

[image: storyboard]

**ButtonEvent**

```swift
    @IBAction func DetailFuc(_ sender: Any) {
    }
```

**WebView Controller**

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

let globalUrl = Global()

class UsageDetail: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UsageWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usageIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    func loadWebPage() {
        let detailUrl = globalUrl.getAgreeURL()
        let myUrl = URL(string: detailUrl)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
        UsageWebView.load(myRequest)
        
        UsageWebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebPage()
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if UsageWebView.isLoading {
                usageIndicator.startAnimating()
                usageIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
                usageIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I took out the Internet line and tried it, but I couldn't see it.

In addition, I would like to use the indicator as a png file. I have a large number of png files.  How can I use an animation of an indicator with it?

Thanks in advance

*************************** Edit start ******************************

I tried it after I saw the answer but there was an error.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

let globalUrl = Global()

class UsageDetail: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UsageWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usageIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    func loadWebPage() {
        let detailUrl = globalUrl.getAgreeURL()
        let myUrl = URL(string: detailUrl)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
        UsageWebView.load(myRequest)
        
        UsageWebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebPage()
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if UsageWebView.isLoading {
                usageIndicator.startAnimating()
                usageIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
                usageIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    extension UsageDetail : WKNavigationDelegate { // get error 'Declaration is only valid at file scope'
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            usageIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
    
}
```

*************************** EditTWO start ******************************

```swift
//
//  UsageDetail.swift
//  dadadac
//
//  Created by taehong on 06/09/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Smart Core. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

let globalUrl = Global()

class UsageDetail: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var UsageWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usageIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    //MARK: View controller lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebPage()
    }
    
    //MARK: initialise webView
    func loadWebPage() {
        let detailUrl = "globalUrl.getAgreeURL()"
        guard let myUrl = URL(string: detailUrl) else {
            //report invalid URL
            return
        }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
        UsageWebView.navigationDelegate = self //Cannot assign value of type 'UsageDetail' to type 'WKNavigationDelegate?'
        UsageWebView.load(myRequest)
    }
    
    
    extension UsageDetail : WKNavigationDelegate {  // Declaration is only valid at file scope
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            usageIndicator.startAnimating()
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
    
}
```

I can see Two Error `Cannot assign value of type 'UsageDetail' to type 'WKNavigationDelegate?'` And `Declaration is only valid at file scope`
*************************** EditTWO end ******************************

Comment: How about start the indicator using `didStartProvisionalNavigation ` and stop it using `didFinish navigation`? They are both WKWebview delegate and remove the needs of using KVO in your case, your check `if keyPath == "loading"` might be incorrect, can be `isLoading` perhasp?

Comment: Hi @Tj3n `keyPath == "loading"` is work But `UsageWebView.isLoading` is Not work. What's wrong????

Comment: "Declaration is only valid at file scope". Use extension outside class

Comment: @Vikky Oh Thanks you. And as you can see from my question, I want to change the indicator to a png file and use it like a gif. What can you do? Besides that, I want to use the indicator as a png file. I have a lot of png files.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364504/swift-how-to-animate-images
or this https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif

Comment: @Vikky  I can't use the .gif file. Isn't the first link an image view? I'm an indicator, not an image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding observer is also not a bad approach but I think easiest way will be to conforms the `WKNavigationDelegate` and also try to avoid force unwrapping when creating URL (if you have some spaces or bad characters this will crash your app. So always try to make you of optional chaining) like I mentioned below

Calling loadWebPage in viewDidLoad.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

let globalUrl = Global()

class UsageDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UsageWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usageIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    //MARK: View controller lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadWebPage()
    }

    //MARK: initialise webView
    private func loadWebPage() {
        let detailUrl = "globalUrl.getAgreeURL()"
        guard let myUrl = URL(string: detailUrl) else {
            //report invalid URL
            return
        }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
        UsageWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        UsageWebView.load(myRequest)
    }
}

extension UsageDetail : WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        usageIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: I was added in UsageDetail.swift file But it is error `Declaration is only valid at file scope`

Comment: I can see Two Error `Cannot assign value of type 'UsageDetail' to type 'WKNavigationDelegate?'` And `Declaration is only valid at file scope`

Comment: it's worked Thanks you. And as you can see from my question, I want to change the indicator to a png file and use it like a gif. What can you do? Besides that, I want to use the indicator as a png file. I have a lot of png files.

Comment: Yes, I want the pictures of the png files to be like animation. It should be applied to the indicator.

Comment: @iosbegindevel remove `}` from your edited question, this will resolve the compile time error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try put the code in 'observeValue' a dispatch async:

```swift
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "loading" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if self.UsageWebView.isLoading {
                self.usageIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.usageIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                self.usageIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.usageIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh~ Hi @Soukipedia Would you like to see my edited question? Why are there two errors?

Comment: @iosbegindevel You need to comfort your 'UserDetail' class to 'WKNavigationDelegate' do it by below code:
```swift
extension UserDetail: WKNavigationDelegate {
}
```

Comment: ah sorry :) you already wrote the extension but you must write it out side the class's scope, for animating with pngs did you mean swapping them quickly to animate?